# How to render an animated gif to the screen using SDL2?

Tags: animation, rendering, sdl2

So, I have an animated gif that is 5 frames (not the same as what is seen in [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/14_animated_sprites_and_vsync/index.php)). Upon opening, my gif is already animating, unlike the png in the above tutorial. 
How can I render it to the screen using SDL2?

The code I have now only renders the gif when I close out the window, and even then, it is only for a split second and I can only see one frame. How can I improve my code?

This is the code that implements the game's main loop:

```
#include "game.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    init();

    SDL_Texture* texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "male_base-test-anim.gif");
    SDL_Rect base;
    base.x = 0;
    base.y = 0;
    base.w = 948;
    base.h = 335;

    bool quit = false;

    SDL_Event e;

    while( !quit )
    {
        //Handle events on queue
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
            //User requests quit
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &base);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    texture = NULL;
    exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you want to move your rendering inside the game loop:

```
while( !quit )
{
    //Handle events on queue
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
    {
        //User requests quit
        if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
        {
            quit = true;
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &base);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Now the first frame of the animation should be visible always when the window is visible.

SDL doesn't support playing animations from .gif files. You want to either follow the advice in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36410301/3450269) which addresses the issue or split your .gif frames into separate image files that contain a single frame (or into a spritesheet) and write your own animation system on that, either display a new texture if you choose to use separate images or modify the source rectangle if you went with the spritesheet approach.